# I am trying to add JPanels into a GridbagLayout, but they don't appear

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

This is the code.

```
    public class Habitacion extends JFrame{
   ArrayList <JButton> botones=new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<ascensor> ascensores=new ArrayList();
   boolean ban=true;
   int numeroX=0;
    int numeroY=0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    JPanel botonesPanel;
    JPanel panelAscensores;
    public Habitacion(){         
    //JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
    this.setTitle("ascensor");
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(1366,768);
    this.botonesPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 1));
    this.panelAscensores= new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        numeroX=0;
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(ascensores.size()!=10){
                ascensores.add(new ascensor(5+numeroX,20+numeroY));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
                c.gridx = j;
                c.gridy = 0;
                this.panelAscensores.add(ascensores.get(j), c);
                ascensores.get(j).setBounds(0+numeroX,0,100,720);
            }
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       this.add(botonesPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
         this.add(panelAscensores,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
```

This is the elevator class. There's more to the habitacion class (which is a Frame), but it's a MouseListener that I can't implement without visualizing the Lables

```
public class ascensor extends JPanel implements Runnable{
 public int posX,y,newY,puertaDer,puertaIzq;
 //MiMouseAdapter e=new MiMouseAdapter();
 Thread hilo;
 boolean ban=true;

public ascensor(int posX,int posY){
    this.posX=posX;
    this.y=posY;
    this.newY=posY;
    puertaDer=posX;
    puertaIzq=posX+40;
    hilo=new Thread(this);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int numero=0;
    Boolean bandera=true;

    while(true){
    while(bandera){
        if(newY < y)
            numero=-1;
        else
            numero=1;
        System.out.println(y);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
        y=y+numero;
        if(y==newY)                
            hilo.suspend();
        repaint();
    }       
    System.out.println("posicion Y:");
    System.out.println(newY);
    repaint();
    }

}
 @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D pluma=(Graphics2D)g;

    g.drawRect(posX,newY+10,40, 50);
    pluma.setColor(Color.red);
    pluma.drawLine(puertaDer, 10+newY, puertaDer, 60+newY);
    pluma.drawLine(puertaIzq, 10+newY,puertaIzq, 60+newY);
    }
  }
}
```

Ascensores, in this context, is a class that extends from JLAbel. It showed perfectly with a GridLAyout, the problem is a I have to move these panels when the user triggers an event. I figured it would be easier to just move the elements within a GridBagLayout, but it doesn't seem to be working. By the way, this works just like Elevators would work in real life, so that's the event I am reffering to. If anyone got an idea for that it would be much appreciated, too.

Comment: Paste your full class code, current code doesn't make sense

Comment: `GridBagConstraints` haven't something with `ascensores.get(j).setBounds(0+numeroX,0,100,720);`, have to decide if GBC or NullLayout

Comment: and idea talking about GridLayout

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please reduce the 'full code' (or whatever that mess is) down to an SSCCE.

Comment: In `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;`  `CENTER` is not a valid value for `GridBagConstraints.fill`. Not that it causes the problem, but you have to learn how to properly do a clean, correct, usage of GridBagLayout. I'd recommend to do a simple Frame application to test and learn it.

Comment: Please have a look at this wonderful example [Subway Simulation](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) by @trashgod, hopefully this might be able to help :-) The term `Elevators` made me remember, that I had seen such a thingy before, so I presented the link to you too :-)